# Making Excel file with desired name from XML in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I got XML file with structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2017-04-26T12:03:30" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">UIValues are used</log>
    </header>
```

After doing my job, I need to save pandas dataframe to Excel file (`.csv` or `.xlsx`), but filename needs to be *"log dateTime"*.

So desired output filename would be:  `2017-04-26T12:03:30.xlsx` or `2017-04-26T12:03:30.csv`.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: in other word, you want to fetch the attribute `dateTime` in tag `log`?

Comment: @Tiny.D
I wanted to take tag log and make filename by that, but I do find another way for that. Thanks :)